# How to reference a specific worksheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to loop through all the files in a parent folder and hide a particular tab.  I get an error and can't seem to figure out how to resolve it.

I get an error on this line:

var sheet = file.getSheetByName("ACCESS")

That states

```
function hidetab() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var folder=DriveApp.getFolderById('1yCHPXGrgXtj7VP9mCCGDRTJdYAfODBZH');
  subfolders = folder.getFolders() 
  while(subfolders.hasNext()){
  var fold = subfolders.next()
  var files=fold.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS); 
     while(files.hasNext()){     
        var file=files.next();        
        var sheet = file.getSheetByName("ACCESS")

         sheet.hidesheet();
        //Logger.log(file)
    };  

  };
};
```

The error I get is that Cannot find function getSheetByName in object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to find all Spreadsheet in the specific folder.
- You want to hide a sheet, which has the sheet name of `ACCESS`, from the found Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- `files.next()` returns the object of file. This is not the object as the Spreadsheet.

  - So please use `SpreadsheetApp.open(file)`.
- Please modify `hidesheet()` to `hideSheet()`.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
var sheet = file.getSheetByName("ACCESS")
sheet.hidesheet();
```

To:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheetByName("ACCESS");
if (sheet) sheet.hideSheet();
```

#### References:

- [Class FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)
- [open(file)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openfile)
- [hideSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideSheet())

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.